# Group timestamp by hour in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a lot of syslog documents in Mongo, below is an example. What I would like to do is grouping them by day/hour/month in a chart. The value would be a count of documents in a certain period in time.

```
{
    u'syslog_message': u'[10724525.839722] [UFW BLOCK] IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=9.8.7.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=50 ID=55384 PROTO=TCP SPT=349 DPT=123 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ',
    u'received_from': u'1.3.5.7:1234',
    u'@version': u'1',
    u'@timestamp': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 15, 9, 55),
    u'syslog_timestamp': u'Nov 20 15:09:55',
    u'syslog_facility': u'user-level',
    u'syslog_severity': u'notice',
    u'host': u'2.4.6.8:2468',
    u'syslog_program': u'kernel',
    u'syslog_hostname': u'server01',
    u'received_at': u'2014-11-20 20:09:55 UTC',
    u'message': u'<4>Nov 20 15:09:55 server01 kernel: [10724525.839722] [UFW BLOCK] IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=2.3.4.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=50 ID=55384 PROTO=TCP SPT=1234 DPT=543 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ',
    u'_id': ObjectId('546e4a93e98673fe8f11a4d2'),
    u'type': u'syslog',
    u'syslog_severity_code': 5,
    u'syslog_facility_code': 1
}
```

I use [Chartkick](https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py) to present this data in Python with Flask, the result is nice but all the messages are on the chart one by one. I would like te make buckets for months, weeks, hours, etc.

For this I can use the value in key '@timestamp'. This works fine but grouping on a count within Python means first retrieving all documents and that can't be right :D

---

Question:

What is the right query that I can use within Pymongo to get the count_by_week etc. or should I use something like an aggregation on the server and what would this look like?

[image: mongo dashboard]
Four servers, notice the flat-line above due to a lack of count-in-time-grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either want to update the counts as you insert, as @alernerdev suggested, or you want to do an aggregation on the server. I'm not familiar with Pymongo, but it looks like it uses syntax very similar to MongoDB's JavaScript driver, which I have used. So to do this as a server-side [aggregation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html), you would do something like:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
        {"$group": {"_id": {"week": {"$week": "$@timestamp"}, "year": {"$year": "$@timestamp"}}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
    ])
```

This will group the log entries by year and week-of-year, and count the number of documents in each group.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work, my timestamp is not in the format Mongo needs so I cannot tell for sure. "can't convert from BSON type String to Date"

Comment: Storing dates as strings is a mistake -- you cant do range searches, for example. Its a common mistake, but you need to change that

Answer (score 1):

you should structure your schema in a way that matches how you are going to use it during retrieval -- in other words, do your data aggregation on the way into the database.  For every insert, use $inc and $set and update whatever stats you need by hour, day, week, etc.

Comment: Yes, that sounds great. But I did not find out how to build such an ingestion transformation. There are a lot of examples but not where they go, how to view them, change them, etc. Do you have a pointer maybe?

Comment: take a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/   ---- it will give you ideas.  The keyword you want to google for is "pre aggregation"

Comment: I've split this question, was not smart of me to combine two subjects. Other half of my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129194/data-transformation-during-load