# Data transformation during load

Tags: mongodb, logstash

On my server runs an application called 'logstash'. This application receives log entries from multiple servers and uploads them as JSON documents to MongoDB. Works like a charm.

Example:

```
{
    u'syslog_message': u'[10724525.839722] [UFW BLOCK] IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=9.8.7.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=50 ID=55384 PROTO=TCP SPT=349 DPT=123 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ',
    u'received_from': u'1.3.5.7:1234',
    u'@version': u'1',
    u'@timestamp': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 15, 9, 55),
    u'syslog_timestamp': u'Nov 20 15:09:55',
    u'syslog_facility': u'user-level',
    u'syslog_severity': u'notice',
    u'host': u'2.4.6.8:2468',
    u'syslog_program': u'kernel',
    u'syslog_hostname': u'server01',
    u'received_at': u'2014-11-20 20:09:55 UTC',
    u'message': u'<4>Nov 20 15:09:55 server01 kernel: [10724525.839722] [UFW BLOCK] IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=2.3.4.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=50 ID=55384 PROTO=TCP SPT=1234 DPT=543 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ',
    u'_id': ObjectId('546e4a93e98673fe8f11a4d2'),
    u'type': u'syslog',
    u'syslog_severity_code': 5,
    u'syslog_facility_code': 1
}
```

But the data is not exactly how I want it to be. I need to convert string to date, add some elements based on other elements and more 'transformations' on each document that is loaded into a specific collection.

What is the default way to handle this and where is this entire process documented?

Answer (score 3):

Logstash has a number of filter plugins that can be used to add, delete, and modify message fields. The [Logstash documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/) lists them all. Judging by your example message above I'd say there already are a number of filters in place. It sounds like you'll at least need an additional [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) and a [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) to accomplish what you're outlining.

Comment: Thank you. I use ISODATE in logstash at the moment but in Mongo it is a string again, so that's a bit weird and not helping. Nonetheless, I would like to edit the data only in one place and that would be during load into Mongo in this particular case.